# PSU plugs don't line up with CPU power on motherboard

Tags: power-supply, power, computer-building

My 650-watt power supply came with many connectors. There is a problem, however: on the left side of both 8-pin connectors, the arrangement is wrong (the roundish-bottomed and square pins are swapped around with relation to the arrangement on my motherboard). I can only plug 10 of the 12 pins in.

The computer won't turn on. Is this the reason, and if so, what is the solution?

Edit: The lighting on the motherboard *does* turn on, so it is getting some power. If I unplug the GPU and try again, I get the same sparse signs of life and nothing more. In other words: the wall plug is fine, the PSU is probably fine, the problem does seem to be with the CPU power.

Edit again, since it can only help to include more info:

Board is Gigabyte Z390 GAMING X ATX LGA1151.

PSU is Antec Earthwatts Gold Pro 650 W 80+ Gold Certified Semi-modular ATX

Comment: sounds like you're trying to use a pcie connector instead of the cpu cable.  there is only 1 8 pin cable for the cpu, there are several pcie cables.

Comment: My PSU has nothing relevant with just one on it, so I have no idea what you're talking about.The PCIE cable is very clearly labeled as such, and it's plugged into the GPU.

Comment: Wait. Never mind. It's on now. The other pci cable for some reason it's labeled as such, I guess. I plugged another 4-pin into the middle of the 8-pin arrangement, and now it's working. Odd, but whatever.